# Problems with pasrseInt()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, nan, parseint

I cant seem to work out why parseInt() is not working properly in my code when I try to pass numbers through to my function parameters. It seems to keep coming up with NaN both in my array and the function return value.

What I am trying to do is when values are keyed into the input fields the index percentage of these two values appears in the HTML and stores the value in an array. I am using a function for this because I want to have over twenty outlet calculations. I am also struggling with refactoring this code as I don't have a lot of experience with JS. Any help would be really appreciated.
Here is my HTML.

```js
function outletIndex(actual, design) {
    
    let result1 = actual / design * 100;
    var indexArray = [];
    indexArray.push(result1);
    console.log(indexArray, result1);
    if (!isNaN(result1)) {
    document.getElementById("percentage").textContent = `${result1.toFixed(1)}%`;
    
  }
}
  const x = parseInt(document.getElementById("outlet_actual_1" ).valueAsNumber);
  const y = parseInt(document.getElementById("outlet_design_1").valueAsNumber);
  
  const outlet1Index = outletIndex(x, y);
```

```html
 <table>
      <tr>
        <div class="form-group row 1" id="outlets1">
          <td><label
            >Outlet Design</label>
            <input
              name = "outlet 1 design"
              class="form-control design_1"
              id="outlet_design_1"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Outlet 1 Design"
              
            />
          </td>
          <td><label
            >Outlet Actual</label>
            <input
            name="outlet 1 actual"
              class="form-control actual_1"
              id="outlet_actual_1"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Outlet 1 Actual"
              onblur="outletIndex();"
            />
          </td>
          <td><label
            >Outlet Balance</label>
            <input
              name="outlet_balance"
              class="form-control"
              input value=""
              id="outlet_balance_1"
              type="text" 
              placeholder="Outlet 1 Balance"        
            />
          </td><td>
            <div class="proportion" id="percentage">

            </div>
          </td>
        </div>
      </tr>
```

Comment: `<input>` elements don't have any content. You're looking for the `.value` property.

Comment: Also, pass a radix to `parseInt` to make sure it converts the string correctly.

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties). You _already_ have `<input type="number">`, so simply get `document.getElementById("outlet_actual_1").valueAsNumber`, etc.

Comment: Ok - I will try that!

Comment: ok so i have tried .valueAsNumber and also Number(document.getElementById("outlet_actual_1").valueAsNumber;

Comment: This question is _clearly_ reproducable and isn't caused by a typo. Not sure what the close voters were thinking. It's not the best question, but it is _far_ from the worst.

Comment: @elsquidge `.valueAsNumber` is _already_ a number. Why do you parse or convert it again?

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onblur` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is the code that reads `x` and `y` runs *before* any valuie is in them.

The second problem is when you `blur` the control with id `outlet_actual_1` you call your method, but with no arguments, when it expects `actual` and `design` to be passed in as arguments.

Finally if using `valueAsNumber` there's no need to use `parseInt`. If you do want to use it then read the `value` and make sure you use the radix like `parseInt(document.getElementById("outlet_actual_1" ).value, 10)`

The simple way to get this going is to move the code that reads `x` and `y` inside the method and remove the arguments, but there's probably more to it than that, I suspect you want to recalculate any time *either* field changes so lets add that too:

```js
function outletIndex() {
    const actual = document.getElementById("outlet_actual_1" ).valueAsNumber || 0 ;
    const design = document.getElementById("outlet_design_1").valueAsNumber || 0 ;
    let result1 = actual / design * 100;
    var indexArray = [];
    indexArray.push(result1);
    console.log(indexArray, result1);
    if (!isNaN(result1)) {
    document.getElementById("percentage").textContent = `${result1.toFixed(1)}%`;
    
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <div class="form-group row 1" id="outlets1">
          <td><label
            >Outlet Design</label>
            <input
              name = "outlet 1 design"
              class="form-control design_1"
              id="outlet_design_1"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Outlet 1 Design"
              onblur="outletIndex();"
            />
          </td>
          <td><label
            >Outlet Actual</label>
            <input
            name="outlet 1 actual"
              class="form-control actual_1"
              id="outlet_actual_1"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Outlet 1 Actual"
              onblur="outletIndex();"
            />
          </td>
          <td><label
            >Outlet Balance</label>
            <input
              name="outlet_balance"
              class="form-control"
              input value=""
              id="outlet_balance_1"
              type="text" 
              placeholder="Outlet 1 Balance"        
            />
          </td><td>
            <div class="proportion" id="percentage">

            </div>
          </td>
        </div>
      </tr>
```

There are many further improvements that can be made to your code, I'd start off reading about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than using inline event handlers like `onblur`